# palindromeRearrangin CodeSignal hidden tests

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this . I passed 18 tests from 20 . 2 of them are hidden and I cant understand what are those 2 scenarios. Please tell me if you see something wrong here . I saw many solutions on the WEB, but I want to understand what is wrong with my own code.

****For inputString = "aabb", the output should be
palindromeRearranging(inputString) = true.**
We can rearrange "aabb" to make "abba", which is a palindrome.**

Here is my code:

```
boolean palindromeRearranging(String str) {

    Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(stack.contains(str.charAt(i))){
            stack.pop();
            continue;
        }
        stack.push(str.charAt(i));
    }

    if(stack.size()>1) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What scenarios are failing? It is difficult to debug without a proper expected result

Comment: I think the order you remove the letters is important but you are just popping letters regardless of the input char. Try your code on "abcabc". You algo returns false, but it can be made into a palindrome: "abccba".

Answer (score 1):

When you're by using condition `stack.contains(str.charAt(i))`,
find out that current checking character `str.charAt(i)` is already present in Stack,

you need to remove that particular repeating character instead of the last character present in Stack.

so only `stack.pop()` is a mistake in code.

Answer (score 0):

One of those scenarios in my case :
"abcabc" . Should return true, but instead it returns false. I sorted the String first then my algorithm worked :)